# First heaven in Al Isra wa Al Miraj

Tags: hadith, miraj

My question is - during the Night Journey Muhammad (peace be upon him) went to the first Heaven. Was it As Samaa ad Dunya?
So, we can see As Samaa ad Dunya, but was the part where Muhammad (peace be upon him) went from the unseen? I mean, the angel guardian of the first heaven, and Adam (peace be upon him) being in the first heaven.
Does it mean that there is a seen and an unseen part of As Samaa ad Dunya?